# Delete a user with Mongoose, Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, crud

I am new to Express and MongoDB. I created a small web app in Node.js and am using Express.js and Mongoose. I can succesfully create a user and have a user sign in but I am having trouble with a user being able to delete their account.

I have a user.js file in my routes folder which is where I am writing the code to signup, signin, delete, etc. Here is a link to the project on GitHub ( https://github.com/NicholasGati/shopping-cart-2 ). The button to delete a user's account is in views/user/edit.hbs. I put the button in a form. When I click the button, the user is not deleted and I am redirected to '/' for some reason. Note: '/:id' in my routes/user.js file becomes '/user/:id'.

Here is the code in the routes/user.js file for the delete method:

```
router.delete('/:id', isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      req.flash("error", err);
      return res.redirect("/user/edit");
    }

    req.flash("success", "Your account has been deleted.");
    req.logout();
    return res.redirect("/shop/coffee");
  });
});
```

Here is the form in views/user/edit.hbs:

```
<form action="/user/{{user.id}}" method="delete">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Account</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, here is the isLoggedIn function:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect("/");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are new I think I should lead you to find the problem yourself:)

1. Make sure about form methods.
2. Make sure the route for user deletion is called.

If the markup doesn't seem right I am sorry cas I am using my phone to post this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Saeid! I thought about your first point to check the form method and tried method="post" instead of the method="delete" and changed route.delete() to route.post() in my routes/user.js file. I then added a hidden field in the form with the csrf token and it worked! Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Your welcome @NicholasGati. I think you could use `delete` method also.

Comment: And if you feel that an answer help you to solve your problem it will be better to give a vote.

Comment: I don't yet have the reputation to vote answers but when I do, I will upvote your answer. Thanks Saeid!

Comment: @NicholasGat I hope that you will get the reputations asap but you also should chose the best answer for your question :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.  I used an XMLHttpRequest from the client side in order to do this.   I'm sorry I'm not experienced enough to explain why it worked this way and not from the node end, but it may have to do with form data being inherently designed to pass information, not delete information.  In any case, try this solution.

## In your client side code:

Your button code (form action shouldn't matter, and for that matter, the  tag shouldn't either, since the logic is handled in the JS, but this is what I used):

```
<a href="/user/{{user.id}}"><button id = "del-btn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
```

Script to send HTTP request from the button click, this code should go in the same file as your button above, or as an include JS file that the HTML page has imported:

```
<script>
        var del_btn = document.getElementById("del-btn");
        del_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

            var user = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("DELETE", "/user/" + user._id);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    window.location.href = "/users";
                }
            };
            xhr.send();


            //make XMLHttpRequest to delete the poll here
        }, false);
</script>
```

in your server side route, note how the response is just a success code. It's the XMLHTTP Request from the client side that does the redirection:

```
  app.delete('/user/:id', isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
          User.remove({
            _id: req.params.id,
            ownerID: req.user._id
          }, function (err, user) {
            if (err)
              return console.error(err);

            console.log('User successfully removed from polls collection!');
            res.status(200).send();


          });

  });
```

Comment: Thanks Shazam. Strangely, the 'delete' methods didn't work but when I changed them to 'post', it all worked fine. I am still not sure why that is, but since changing the routes/user.js file to use router.post() and method='post' in the form, the user was successfully deleted. I also had to add a csrf token in the form as a hidden field too. Thanks for your response!

Comment: use package `multer`, `npm install --save multer` to support delete request.